# Totally random 502 error on private network (apache)

Tags: laravel, apache, networking, lamp

longtime lurker, first off thank you all for the knowledge over the years.

OK I have a baffling, inconsistent error that is proving very difficult to fix.
The setup: Digital ocean LAMP droplet hosting a laravel site, recently deployed so it's all fairly up to date.

The problem: while inside one particular organization's network, the site will return a 502 error 10-20% of every request. This error will result immediately on any request, within msecs, so not a timeout issue. Then it will resolve immediately on refresh. A few clicks later then 502 then refresh and its gone.

I know, 502 is pointing at my server, but this error has *never* occurred outside their network for anyone using the site. Literally not one time for any other user from any device or other network has this problem.

I've checked the error logs, I don't have any errors from the offending IP.
I've checked the firewall, doing its thing but nothing fishy and again nothing pointing back to this network.
I've cycled the server, restarted apache, set the servername, I've even cleaned up some of the routes in case it's bad code (maybe I didn't clean them up well enough? the routing isn't spectacular, but again, no problems outside this network).

Also worth noting: while inside this organization I have seen on at least a few occasions the same 502 behavior on other very reputable websites. But it's far less frequent, and not generalizable to all sites (never had it happen on SO for example).

Can someone at least point me in any direction at all to diagnose this problem? It has to be on my end. Could "bad code" interacting with this particular network cause this behavior? Has anyone ever seen anything like this happen?

Comment: I usually receive a Bad Gateway when its out of memory, access your server and monitor your memory usage with `top -i`

Comment: Are you sure the 502 is coming from your end? It could be that the certain network that gets this issue is using a proxy that is overloaded

Comment: I appreciate the input -- I have my doubts about memory because I can resolve the error on refresh no problem. Resource issue was my first thought, so I resized the droplet. I've been onsite troubleshooting this with them and even though it has happened a few times on other big brand websites, it happens an order of magnitude more on this laravel app when on their network. May be a proxy issue on their end -- very large org using thin clients. But again, not all websites, and not even this one all the time. Could poor code/routing cause random 502s on *one* particular network ?

Comment: Have you checked to see if apache is running well?